# Decode all possibilities from a given encoded ascii string

Tags: java, python, ascii

A string is encoded by performing the following sequence of actions:
1. Replace each character with its ASCII value representation.
2. Reverse the string.

For example, the table below shows the conversion from the string 
`"HelloWorld"` to the ASCII string `"7210110810811187111114108100"`:

Character

```
H  e   l   l   o    W  o   r   l   d
```

ASCII Value

```
72 101 108 108 111  87 111 114 108 100
```

The ASCII string is then reversed to get the encoded string `"0018014111117811180180110127`".

The characters in encoded string are within the range 10 - 126 which include special characters.

I need to write a function that must **decode the encoded string** and **return the list of ways** in which it can be decoded.

I could not get a work around to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [MCVE]. Your question "any help?" is too broad.

Comment: I would try posting on the [CS stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) but I would try a backtracking solution or maybe a dynamic programming solution since the substrings can probably translate to overlapping subproblems. It depends on how big an input you need to handle.

Comment: You want the solution in java or python ?

Comment: @d-coder Any of the two.

Comment: Cool. Now show us something you wrote and what you tried ? We can help you in correcting your solution but we can't write a solution for you! Not my homework or interview question you see!

Answer (score 2):

```
solutions = []
currentSolution = ''
unprocessed = ''


def decode(s):
    flipped = s[::-1]
    global solutions
    global unprocessed
    global currentSolution
    currentSolution = ''
    unprocessed = flipped
    _decode()
    return solutions


def is_valid(split):
    if split.startswith('0'):
        return False
    value = int(split)
    if value < 10 or value > 126:
        return False
    return True


def _decode():
    global unprocessed
    global currentSolution
    global solutions
    if len(unprocessed) == 0:
        solutions.append(currentSolution)
    else:
        possible_splits = list()
        possible_splits.append(unprocessed[0:2])
        possible_splits.append(unprocessed[0:3])

        for split in possible_splits:
            if is_valid(split):
                decoded_character = chr(int(split))
                currentSolution += decoded_character
                unprocessed = unprocessed[len(split):]
                _decode()
                currentSolution = currentSolution[0: len(currentSolution) - 1]
                unprocessed = split + unprocessed


def main():
    final_solutions = decode('0018014111117811180180110127')
    print(final_solutions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rico , adding a converted python code for Rico's solution for people unfamiliar with JavaScript.

Comment: You are able to upvote answers and accept them now. (not recommended to upvote your own answer)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that you're asking a very computer science question--one I'd see in an intro data structures/algorithms class. I'm assuming you know some of the terminology I'll be using here given that context.

---

I used [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to calculate every possible split and if the split was valid (e.g. used all numbers), then I added it to a list of solutions.

You'll notice that it isn't the most efficient algorithm but it still works on your input. I believe the time complexity is something like `O(2^n)` (though I may be wrong about that) because, @Mulliganaceous pointed out, at each decision to split, you create another branch which has at most two options.

Furthermore, since you want all possible ways, you need to exhaust this search tree until you find all solutions. You might be able to get a faster algorithm using [dynamic programming](https://youtu.be/OQ5jsbhAv_M) but I haven't thought about this problem enough to do so.

So here's the `O(2^n)` solution:

The code below has these steps in the comments.

1. initial some state. you need:

   1. an empty list of solutions
   2. the current solution being considered
   3. the current unprocessed substring
2. kick off the backtracking with an initial `decode` function/method. in this method, flip the input and assign that to the unprocessed substring. You can additionally reset the other state parameters if you plan on running this function more than once. call the recursive `_decode` function to kick off the backtracking.
3. in the backtracking method, check to see if a solution is found (base case when the unprocessed string is empty). if it has been found, add the current solution to the list of solutions
4. after the solution check, generate a list of all possible splits for the current unprocessed string. For example: let's say the unprocessed string is `123456`. For this string, there are only 2 possible splits for this branch: `12` and `123`. If the unprocessed string was just `78`, there would only be one possible split: `78`.
5. iterate through the list of possible splits for the current branch of the implicit search tree. Check to see if the split is valid. In this case, your requirements said the split is valid if the parsed string as a number is between 10 and 126 inclusive. Additionally, the string with the split *cannot start with zero* because when the string is originally made, there is no possibility for padded zeros.
6. if the split is valid, then change the state. In this case, add the decoded character to the solution and remove the split from the unprocessed string (because you processed it)
7. go deeper. recursively call the `_decode` method. this will keep going down the search tree until it doesn't have any options.
8. backtrack. once the callstack comes back up from this call, it means that it didn't find any options. you have to undo the state you set above it. in this case, remove the character from the current solution and add the split back to the unprocessed string.

---

And that's that!

But here's some javascript code (the only reason it's in javascript is so you can press the "Run code snippet" button in browser).

If you're on mac, hit `Cmd + option I` and then click "Run code snippet"
If you're on windows, his `F12` and then click "Run code snippet"

You'll see your browser open up a debugger. *Step through the code*. See what it's doing.

```js
// 1
let solutions = [];
let currentSolution = '';
let unprocessed = '';

function range(n) {
  const list = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  return list;
}

// 2
function decode(input) {
  const flipped = input
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('');

  solutions = [];
  currentSolution = '';
  unprocessed = flipped;

  _decode();

  return solutions.slice();
}

function isValid(split) {
  if (split.startsWith('0')) return false;
  const value = parseInt(split, 10);
  if (value < 10) return false;
  if (value > 126) return false;
  return true;
}

function _decode() {
  // 3
  if (unprocessed.length === 0) {
    solutions.push(currentSolution);
  }
  // 4
  const possibleSplits = range(2)
    .map(i => i + 1)
    .filter(i => i < unprocessed.length)
    .map(i => unprocessed.substring(0, i + 1));

  // 5
  for (const split of possibleSplits) {
    if (isValid(split)) {
      const decodedCharacter = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(split, 10));
      // 6
      currentSolution += decodedCharacter;
      unprocessed = unprocessed.substring(split.length);
      // 7
      _decode();
      // 8
      currentSolution = currentSolution.substring(0, currentSolution.length - 1);
      unprocessed = split + unprocessed;
    }
  }
}

debugger;
console.time('calculation time');
const finalSolutions = decode('0018014111117811180180110127');
console.timeEnd('calculation time');
console.log(finalSolutions.length, 'solutions (all but one of them contain special characters)');
console.log(finalSolutions);

console.log('final solutions in ascii code');
console.log(finalSolutions
  .map(solution => solution
    .split('')
    .map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    .map(code => code.toString())
    .join(', ')
  )
  .map(line => `[${line}]`)
  .join('\n')
)
```

> Can you also add an additional part to your code which prints out every char as an ASCII code, each encased in brackets? – Mulliganaceous 24 mins ago

sure thing, see the edited answer.

Edit: updated the `isValid` function to check to see if the string starts with `0`, if it does, then it should not consider that split valid.

Comment: Can you also add an additional part to your code which prints out every char as an ASCII code, each encased in brackets?

Comment: Thanks. I have provided a previous algorithm. Like yours, it is also recursive.

You need to note that given any (unreversed) encoding, there can be up to two possible next characters; namely one with a two-digit ASCII value (10 to 99) and one with a three-digit ASCII value (100 to 126).

Comment: @Mulliganaceous that's a good catch. the algorithm i wrote considers splits of length 1, 2, or 3 but splits of length of 1 are completely unnecessary and will never pass the `isValid` function above. (edit:) it now only considers splits of length 2 or 3

Comment: if you haven't learn backtracking techniques, i would recommend this [video](https://youtu.be/gBC_Fd8EE8A). it's a good conceptual tool 